# Understanding how prototype chaining work?

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

In the below code Cat inherits from Animal and Animal inherits from Living Being. 
My question is how does defining a function in Cat stays with cat even after defining the prototype of Cat to Animal. 
Please clarify ?

```
        var LivingBeing = function (){
        this.hasSenses = true
        };

        LivingBeing.prototype.getSenses = function(){
            return 'senses';
        };
        LivingBeing.prototype.customName = 'livingbeingsss'

        var Animal = function Animal(){
            LivingBeing.call(this);
            this.voice='Animals voice'
        };

        Animal.prototype = Object.create(LivingBeing.prototype);
        Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal; 
        Animal.prototype.speak = function(){
            console.log(this.voice);
        };
        Animal.prototype.customName = 'animalsss' 

        var Cat = function Cat(){
        Animal.call(this);
        this.name='Cat';
        }
        Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
        Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
        Cat.prototype.isacat = function (){
            return true;
        } 

        console.log(Cat.prototype);

        var a = new Cat();
        console.log(a);
        a.speak();
        console.log(a.customName);
        console.log(a.isacat())
```

I did some work looking at the prototype chain in the console log of firefox. As seen below.

```
hasSenses: true
    name: "Cat"
    ​voice: "Animals voice"
           <prototype>: {…}
        ​​   constructor: function Cat()
        ​​   isacat: function isacat()
              <prototype>: {…}
        ​​​      constructor: function Animal()
        ​​​      customName: "animalsss"
        ​​​      speak: function speak()
                  <prototype>: {…}
        ​​​​          constructor: function LivingBeing()
        ​​​​          customName: "livingbeingsss"
        ​​​​          getSenses: function getSenses()
                      <prototype>: {…}
        ​​​​​              __defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()...
```

How does the iscat function defined sits on the cat prototype instead of the animals prototype ?

Didnt we set the cats prototype to animal ? 
Also the output of the below condition are

a.**proto** === Cat.prototype //true
a.**proto** === Animal.prototype //false

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is thoughtfully researched. Thank you! Take a look at markdown formatting issues that will help others better understand your question. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Look at the code: `Cat.prototype.isacat = function() ...` — the code directly assigns to the "isacat" property of the `Cat` prototype.

Comment: Cat 'extends' Animal, but Cat still has its own prototype as well where you can place methods on. `Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` just 'references' the methods of Animal into the Cat prototype as well. So `Cat.ptotoype.isacat()` does not appear on the Animal prototype, only on the Cat prototype.

Comment: "*Didnt we set the cats prototype to animal?*" - no, we did set `Cat.prototype` - the thing that all `new Cat` instances will inherit from - to an object that inherits from `Animal.prototype`. And then we put the `isacat` method on that object which inherits from `Animal.prototype`.